# How to redraw a list in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I have a List in my smalltalk application that gets updated by user events.  The list updates correctly, but it only redraws, repaints, or refreshes whenever the window is forced to redraw.  So it'll appear as it is supposed to, but only when I hide and then reshow the window, or drag it off screen and then bring it back on.

How do I make the App window automatically redraw, whenever the list is updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working by including:

```
self changed: #objectInList
```

In the method of the objects being changed.